# Loopback: Hide some properties for some user roles

Tags: loopbackjs, acl

There is a model like this

```
{
  name,
  budget
}
```

And there is a role `reviewer`

Is there any way to hide the `budget` field for the `reviewer`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a remote hook for that model. For example your code could look like this:

```
MyModel.afterRemote('**', function(ctx, modelInstance, next) {
  if (ctx.result) {
    if (checkIfUserHasRole('reviewer')) { // <-- you need to implement this function
      // if you are going to return a list of items, eg. from Model.find(...) 
      if (Array.isArray(modelInstance)) { 
        ctx.result = ctx.result.map(item => {
          return modifyYourProperties(item); // <-- you need to implement this function
        }
      }
      // if you are going to return a single item, eg. from Model.findById(...)
      else {
        ctx.result = modifyYourProperties(ctx.result); // <-- as above...
        }

      });
    }
  }
  next();
}
```

So now, on every remote call to your model, you can modify the results. They are already processed but not yet returned to the requester, so here is where you can hide desired properties.

Of course, you need to implement methods `checkIfUserHasRole` and `modifyYourProperties` to do what you are going to achieve. You can read more about remote hooks here: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Remote-hooks.html